# How does one load TMX files into a SFML game?

Tags: 2d, sfml

How does one load `.tmx` files from [Tiled](http://www.mapeditor.org) into a SFML game?

Comment: Keep in mind to accept one answer, which both increases your reputation and helps you get help in the future if people see, that you approve of given hints and answers!

Comment: yeah sure.. i got it ..

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion the [tmx-parser](http://code.google.com/p/tmx-parser/) is the most robust library available which I have been using, too. It even supports compression which is the default option in Tiled.

Comment: This, and if that does not please you, you can still export from Tiled to other formats like JSON and parse that, there is a lot of parsers for JSON.

Answer (score 0):

TMX is an xml-based format. You can parse it with any XML-parsing library to extract the level data and convert it into your internal format.

Comment: okay ... got it

Answer (score 0):

Two other options you have are [STP](https://github.com/edoren/STP) and [sfml-tmxloader](https://github.com/fallahn/sfml-tmxloader)

As for the first option I have not tried it. However I've used sfml-tmxloader and found it to be very simple to use, which is also the one I recommend.